# how to track the stored procedure execution by using PRINT statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I Have a stored procedure and its task is that, It will take a file and transfer the records into TEMP table after that will do validation accordingly and then it will put the records into Main Staging table.(Aditionally we have 3 more tables for validation purpose and those are StockIntegrityCheck, IntegrityErrorLog, InterfaceIntegrity )

**Problem:** When an empty file has come(0KB file), It is not supposed to put any entry any of the tables. but it is putting an entry in InteggrityErrorLog Table which is not needed. I want to correct the stored procedure accordingly?

Here is SP:

```
USE [PARAM.DB]

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].        [usp_LDMDB_GMIH_DSOA_STAGING]') AND type in (N'P'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_LDMDB_GMIH_DSOA_STAGING]

GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/*  
Description:    This program will insert records from LDMDB_GMIH_DSO_A_STAGING_TEMP   table to LDMDB_GMIH_DSO_A_STAGING table
*/  

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_LDMDB_GMIH_DSOA_STAGING] 
AS

DECLARE
  @DATA VARCHAR(200),
  @HDRDATA VARCHAR(200),
  @FLAG INT,
  @ErrStmt VARCHAR(500),
  @ProcessDate datetime,
  /* Stock Integrity Changes for I0180 Starts */
  @Integritycheck INT,
  @Totalcount VARCHAR(10),
  @Totalquantity VARCHAR(10),
  @TrackingID VARCHAR(20),
  @count INT,
  @quantity INT;    
  /* Stock Integrity Changes for I0180 Ends */
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  select @ProcessDate =  GETDATE()
  /* Stock Integrity Changes for I0180 Starts */
  SET @count = 0;
  SET @quantity = 0;
  SET @Integritycheck = (SELECT Value from dbo.LDMStockIntegrityCheck where interfacename  = 'I0180' and filename = 'PIZ.HW.NDC.CALLOFF.FILE.LDM');

  /* Stock Integrity Changes for I0180 Ends */
  DECLARE CUR_JOB CURSOR LOCAL 
  FOR
  SELECT DATA FROM LDMDB_GMIH_DSO_A_STAGING_TEMP ORDER BY ROW_ID 
  OPEN CUR_JOB

  IF @@ERROR <> 0  
  BEGIN
    SET @ErrStmt= 'Error while Opening the Cursor'  
    GOTO ERRHDL  
  END  
  -- LOOPING THROUGH EACH RECORD.
  FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_JOB INTO @DATA

  IF @@ERROR <> 0  
  BEGIN  
    SET @ErrStmt= 'Error while Fetching the Record From Cursor'  
    GOTO ERRHDL  
  END

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    SET @FLAG = 0
    IF(SUBSTRING (@DATA,1,1)= '1')
    BEGIN
      SET @HDRDATA = @DATA
      SET @FLAG = 0
      /* Stock Integrity Changes for I0180 Starts */

      IF (@Integritycheck = 1 )
      BEGIN
        SET @TrackingID   = SUBSTRING(@data,19,20);
        SET @Totalcount   =  CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@data,39,10));
        SET @Totalquantity = CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@data,49,15));
      END

      /* Stock Integrity Changes for I0180 Ends */       
    END

    IF(SUBSTRING (@DATA,1,1)= '5')
    BEGIN
      SET @FLAG = 1
      /* Stock Integrity Changes for I0180 Starts */
      IF (@Integritycheck = 1 )
      BEGIN
        SET @count= @count +1 ;
        SET @quantity = @quantity + CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@data,45,09)) ;
      END
      /* Stock Integrity Changes for I0180 Ends */
    END

    IF (@FLAG = 1)
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO LDMDB_GMIH_DSO_A_STAGING 
      (    FileCreationDate,
           GenerationNumber,
           WAREHOUSE_CODE,
           ALLOC_RUN_DATE,
           SUPP_CODE,
           SUPP_LOC_CODE,
           PICKSHEET_NUM,
           UPC,
           DELIVERY_POINT,
           STORE_NUM,
           VALUE_TOTAL_SEND,
           COUNTRY_CODE,
           DISPATCH_PRIORITY,
           QTY,
           ProcessDate
      )
      SELECT  LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(convert( varchar(20),(CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING  (@HDRDATA,2,8), 111)),121),1,10))) FileCreationDate,
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING (@HDRDATA,10,9))) GenerationNumber,
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING (@DATA,2,3)))     WAREHOUSE_CODE ,
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(convert( varchar(20),(CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING (@DATA,5,8), 111)),121),1,10))) ALLOC_RUN_DATE,
              RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',10) + LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING (@DATA,13,4))),5)  SUPP_CODE,
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING (@DATA,17,5)))  SUPP_LOC_CODE,
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING (@DATA,22,6)))    PICKSHEET_NUM,
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING (@DATA,29,8)))    UPC,
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING (@DATA,37,4)))    DELIVERY_POINT,
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING (@DATA,41,4)))    STORE_NUM, 
              (SELECT CASE  WHEN cast(SUBSTRING (@DATA,45,9) AS NUMERIC) < 0 THEN  ('-' +  LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING (@DATA,46,8)))) ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING (@DATA,45,9))) END) VALUE_TOTAL_SEND,
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING (@DATA,54,3)))    COUNTRY_CODE, 
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING (@DATA,57,2)))    DISPATCH_PRIORITY,
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING (@DATA,59,9)))    QTY,
              @ProcessDate

      IF @@ERROR <> 0  
      BEGIN  
        SET @ErrStmt= 'Error while Inserting the Records into the Staging Table'  
        GOTO ERRHDL  
      END
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_JOB INTO @DATA
  END

  CLOSE CUR_JOB
  DEALLOCATE CUR_JOB
  IF (@Integritycheck = 0)
  BEGIN
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
  END

  FINISH:
  BEGIN
    /* Stock Integrity Changes for I0180 Starts */
    IF (@Integritycheck = 0 )
    BEGIN 
      SET @ErrStmt= 'Inserting the Records into the Staging Table Successful'
      PRINT 'Inserting the Records into the Staging Table Successful'
      Return
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN

      IF ((@count = @Totalcount)AND(@quantity = @Totalquantity))
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.LDMInterfaceIntegrity VALUES ('I0180','PIZ.HW.NDC.CALLOFF.FILE.LDM',@TrackingID,@Totalquantity,@Totalcount,@ProcessDate);
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;             
        BEGIN  
          SET @ErrStmt= 'Inserting the Records into the Staging Table Successful';
          Return
        END      

      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        IF (@count <> @Totalcount)
        BEGIN                                   
          INSERT INTO dbo.LDMIntegrityErrorLog VALUES ('I0180','PIZ.HW.NDC.CALLOFF.FILE.LDM',@TrackingID,'Count Mismatch',@ProcessDate);
          PRINT 'Count mismatch';
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN

          INSERT INTO dbo.LDMIntegrityErrorLog VALUES ('I0180','PIZ.HW.NDC.CALLOFF.FILE.LDM',@TrackingID,'Quantity Mismatch',@ProcessDate);
          PRINT 'Quantity Mismatch';
        END

        RETURN;
      END
    END
    /* Stock Integrity Changes for I0180 Ends */
  END
  ERRHDL:  
  BEGIN 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
    RETURN              
  END

END
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you *want* to happen, and what *is* happening. There's a fair amount of code to wade through here, some of which is dependent on other tables, etc. that it's going to be difficult to just guess what your issue is (and it's not even clear what you want to do when you have a 0-byte file)...though, FWIW I'll hazard one anyway - NULL values aren't equal and aren't comparable.

Comment: Sorry for Improper description in it. I want to know in stored procedure that what are all the values(Count,quantity, totalcount and totalquantity) it is taking when a 0 KB file has given as a input. I just want to give the PRINT statements whereever count and quantity has been there. Ideally i want to track the values of count, quantity, totalcount and totalquantity. please help me on how to track these values

Answer (score 0):

Use `RAISERROR ... WITH NOWAIT` as per this (among many others): http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1660/using-the-nowait-option-with-the-sql-server-raiserror-statement/

At certain error levels, `RAISERROR` isn't actually considered an error, so it can be used as an alternative to `PRINT`.

Answer (score 0):

Sql server management studio provide facility to debug the store procedure . by debugging the store procedure you can check value of each variable and which statement executed during execution of the store procedure . 
just put the debug point in statement in store procedure and press debug .

Check http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=618LE_FZCxI